# Can't free() a char*

Tags: c

```
void* password_cracker_thread(void* args) {
    cracker_args* arg_struct = (cracker_args*) args;
    md5hash* new_hash = malloc (sizeof(md5hash));


    while(1)
    {
        char* password = fetch(arg_struct->in);

        if(password == NULL  )
        {
            deposit(arg_struct->out,NULL);
            free(new_hash);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        compute_hash(password,new_hash);
        if(compare_hashes(new_hash,(md5hash**)arg_struct->hashes,arg_struct->num_hashes) != -1)
        {
            printf("VALID_PASS:%s \n",password);
            deposit(arg_struct->out,password);
        }else{
            free(password);

        }
    }

}
```

This is a part of a program, where you get `char*` passwords from a ringbuffer, calculate md5 and compare them and push them into the next buffer if valid.

My problem is now, why can't I free those I don't need?
The whole program will stop if I try to and if I don't, I get memory leaks.

Comment: Evidently you are passing `free()` a changed version of the pointer to  `password`.  It is likely being changed in `compute_hash` or `deposit`.  `free()` does not react well to requests to free memory (location) that has not been allocated.  view the address of `password` throughout the process to see where it is being changed.  `printf("%p", password);`, or debugger.

Comment: Providing definitions of fetch() and deposit() functions will help.

Comment: It all depends on what's happening inside `fetch`, from where the pointer is coming. `new_hash` is directly allocated using `malloc`, but the `password` can be in the middle of an allocated memory block.

Comment: You say "the whole program will stop" if you try to call `free()`. How does it stop? Is there an error message? If so, please include it in the question.

Comment: More of your function definitions are needed to help clarify the question. But given the nature of your  project, I understand why you may be reluctant.  Curious though, why would you want to crack a password?

Comment: `char* fetch(ringbuffer* buf);` so i get a `char*` pointer from fetch which is allocated in a password-generator, when i free it will corrupt my password somehow: 
`any_PASS:hloԡ address: 0x7fa1d40008e0 
any_PASS: address: 0x7fa1d40008e0 
any_PASS:hlpԡ address: 0x7fa1d40009a0` 
this is how it looks like: 1. password + address before free 
2. after free 3. next element

Comment: its my homework of university, sharing solutions is not the best idea :D

Comment: `void to_depo(char* str, ringbuffer* buffer)
{
    char* depo = malloc(sizeof(str));
    memcpy(depo,str,sizeof(&str));
    deposit(buffer,depo);

    return;
}`
this is where is alloc the mem and push it into the ringbuffer

Comment: `void* decrypter_messages_thread(void* args) {
 decrypter_args* arg_struct = (decrypter_args*) args;
 
 FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen(FILENAME,"w+");
 //TODO fetch password from output buffer
 while(1)
 {
        char* pass = fetch(arg_struct->in);
        //nur raus,wenns nix mehr gibt
        if(pass == NULL)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        printf("fetched:%s\n",pass);
        print_solutions(fp,arg_struct,(byte*)pass);
        fflush(fp);
        free(pass);
        printf("freed:%s\n",pass);
    }
}`

Comment: `any_PASS:zw address: 0x7fce4c000a20 
any_PASS:zx address: 0x7fce4c000a80 
any_PASS:zy address: 0x7fce4c000ac0 
any_PASS:zz address: 0x7fce4c000aa0 
any_PASS:aaaL� address: 0x7fce4c000980 
any_PASS:aabL� address: 0x7fce4c000a60 
any_PASS:aacL� address: 0x7fce4c000b00 
 `
it looks like im free'ing too much, when i get from 2 chars too 3 chars

Comment: `free()` is not a general-purpose function for freeing up any memory you like when done with it.    The only pointers that can be passed to `free()` are pointers returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.  Pass any other pointers, and the result is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(str))` and `memcpy(depo,str,sizeof(&str))` both make me shiver. Pointers pointers...

Comment: in C, when calling malloc() and family of functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

"You", and by this I mean your program, can only `free()` storage that was got from `malloc()`-and-friends, and only in the granularity it was got, and only once per chunk of storage.

In the code you show here, you're attempting to `free()` something got from `fetch()`. Since we can't see the definition of that function and you have not provided any documentation of it, our best guess is that

- `fetch()` gives you a pointer to something other than a whole chunk
  got from `malloc()`-et-al; and/or
- some other part of the program not
  shown here `free()`s the relevant chunk itself.